# Disabling the inputs of a table row with a checkbox and vice versa

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

I want to disable the inputs of one row of the table after clicking on the checkbox, but the checkbox remains active so that I can activate the inputs of one row again.
And after registering the form, when I return to this form again, if the check box was checked, the inputs of the same row will be disabled.
I wrote some code, but please complete it. Thank you

```js
function DisableRow(checkBox) {
  var $trElement = $(checkBox).closest("tr");
  $trElement.find("input").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  $trElement.find("select").attr("disabled", "disabled");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('#checkBox').is(':checked')) {

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control mt-1 text-sm " disabled value="@Model.ToList()[i].MablaghKhreedAnjamShode" onkeyup="javascript:this.value=itpro(this.value);" name="[@i].Saiar" required autocomplete="off" />
      <input class="d-none" name="[@i].ProjectId" />
      <input class="d-none" name="id" value="@Model.ToList()[i].ProjectId" />
      <input class="form-control d-none" type="number" name="ListID" value="@Model.ToList()[i].ListId" />

    </td>
    <td>

      <label class="switch">
                            <input id="theCheckBox" type="checkbox" onchange="DisableRow(this)" asp-for="@Model.ToList()[i].VazeetKhareedDarInFasle" value="True">
                            <span class="slider round"></span>
                        </label>
    </td>

    <td>


      <select class=" mt-1 form-control" asp-for="@Model.ToList()[i].NoaeFactor" style="font-size: 12px; width: 130px" required autocomplete="off">

        <option value="" default="" selected="">انتخاب کنید</option>
        <option value="1">خرید</option>
        <option value="2">برگشت از خرید</option>

      </select>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your checkbox is input also ,if you don't want to disable itself,you could select as below :`find("input[type='text']")`

If you want to active it again,you could try:`removeAttr("disabled")`

I tried as below：

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="tr1input1"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="tr1input2"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" onchange="DisableRow(this)" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="tr2input1"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="tr2input2"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            
            <input type="checkbox"  id="checkbox2" onchange="DisableRow(this)" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>    
    
    function DisableRow(e) {
        var targetelement = $(e).closest('tr').find("input[type='text']")
        if (e.checked == true)
        {
            
            targetelement.attr("disabled", "disabled")
        }
        else
        {
            targetelement.removeAttr("disabled")
        }
    }
</script>
<script>
    window.onload=function () {
       
        $("#checkbox2").attr("checked", true)
        
        if( $("#checkbox2").is(':checked'))
        {
            $("#checkbox2").closest('tr').find("input[type='text']").attr("disabled", "disabled")
            
        }
        
    }
</script>
```

Result:

[image]

**Update**

You could try
`$("input[type='checkbox']:checked").closest('tr').find("input[type='text']").attr("disabled", "disabled")`

Comment: Your answer is correct, but when loading your page, you used an ID, but I have a list of checkboxes

Comment: window.onload = function () {
            
            if ($("#checkbox").is(':checked')) {
                $("#checkbox").closest('tr').find("input[type='text']").attr("disabled", 
               "disabled")

            }

Comment: Please edit the answer, I need this

Comment: I‘ve updated my answer,please check it